# What is the use of streamlines in Fluid Mechanics when velocity fields seem sufficient?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

So, **streamlines** are a family of curves which, for every instant in time, are the velocity field envelops.

And in general, **envelopes of a vector field** are the curves whose tangent vector at each point coincides (in direction and sense but not necessarily in magnitude) with the corresponding vector of the vector field.

For reference, I got these definitions from a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQxriImCifY&t=620s).

**What is the use of streamlines in Fluid Mechanics when velocity fields seem sufficient?**

Comment: Sufficient for what? Streamlines are useful for illustrative/visualisation purposes

Comment: But we can still draw the vector field, which is vectors connected to each other. So streamlines are just the vector field but drawn in a smooth way?

Comment: Right. Why not try doing both illustrations and see which is clearer to the viewer? How long will you make your vector arrows? How will they overlap? It can get messy fast

Comment: You're right. Your comment is the answer. Thank you. Sometimes I just get stuck in silly questions.